# Bitcoin Core Node installation

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node, windows, sparrow-wallet

How to verify & install Bitcoin Core node and Sparrow wallet in Windows 11 laptop?  Please tell me step by step. My lap has 8 GB RAM & 500 GB storage (free space would b around 200 GB).

And also what are routine commands I have to use there?